# Ansible command from inside virtualenv?

Tags: virtualenv, ansible

This seems like it should be really simple:

```
tasks:
- name: install python packages
  pip: name=${item} virtualenv=~/buildbot-env
  with_items: [ buildbot ]
- name: create buildbot master
  command: buildbot create-master ~/buildbot creates=~/buildbot/buildbot.tac
```

However, the command will not succeed unless the virtualenv's activate script is sourced first, and there doesn't seem to be provision to do that in the [Ansible command module](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/modules.html#command).

I've experimented with sourcing the activate script in various of .profile, .bashrc, .bash_login, etc, with no luck. Alternatively, there's the shell command, but it seems like kind of an awkward hack:

```
- name: create buildbot master
  shell: source ~/buildbot-env/bin/activate && \
         buildbot create-master ~/buildbot \
         creates=~/buildbot/buildbot.tac executable=/bin/bash
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm also looking for a cleaner answer to this. Am currently using a two line script to do the trick and running it with Ansible's script module.

Comment: JFYI, `${item}` syntax is deprecated and will be removed in future.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The better way is to use the full path to installed script - it will run in its virtualenv automatically:

```
tasks:
- name: install python packages
  pip: name={{ item }} virtualenv={{ venv }}
  with_items: [ buildbot ]
- name: create buildbot master
  command: "{{ venv }}/bin/buildbot create-master ~/buildbot
            creates=~/buildbot/buildbot.tac"
```

Comment: It's worth noting for anyone stumbling across this while scratching their head, that while calling the executable at it's full path _usually_ works, it's not quite exactly the same: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/393#issue-233266934

Comment: cleanest answer by far, without hacking stuff, came here trying to run a luigi daemon installed in a virtualenv, just realised all I have to do is give it the path to the luigid inside the virtualenv dir.

Comment: not all the utilities will install a binary on the virtual env bin folder

Answer (score 26):

This is a genericized version of the wrapper method.

venv_exec.j2:

```
#!/bin/bash
source {{ venv }}/bin/activate
$@
```

And then the playbook:

```
tasks:
  - pip: name={{ item }} virtualenv={{ venv }}
    with_items:
      - buildbot
  - template: src=venv_exec.j2 dest={{ venv }}/exec mode=755
  - command: "{{ venv }}/exec buildbot create-master {{ buildbot_master }}"
```

Comment: not a bad idea. You can even use the script module to do everything in one go

Answer (score 14):

Here's a way to enable the virtualenv for an entire play; this example builds the virtualenv in one play, then starts using it the next.

Not sure how clean it is, but it works. I'm just building a bit on what mikepurvis mentioned here.

```
---
# Build virtualenv
- hosts: all
vars:
  PROJECT_HOME: "/tmp/my_test_home"
  ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/local/bin/python"
tasks:
  - name: "Create virtualenv"
    shell: virtualenv "{{ PROJECT_HOME }}/venv"
           creates="{{ PROJECT_HOME }}/venv/bin/activate"

  - name: "Copy virtualenv wrapper file"
    synchronize: src=pyvenv
                 dest="{{ PROJECT_HOME }}/venv/bin/pyvenv"

# Use virtualenv
- hosts: all
vars:
  PROJECT_HOME: "/tmp/my_test_home"
  ansible_python_interpreter: "/tmp/my_test_home/venv/bin/pyvenv"
tasks:
  - name: "Guard code, so we are more certain we are in a virtualenv"
    shell: echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
    register: command_result
    failed_when: command_result.stdout == ""
```

pyenv wrapper file:

```
#!/bin/bash
source "$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )/activate"
python $@
```

Comment: This looks great; I'll need to experiment with the implications of doing this inside a role, but it should be straightforward setting `ansible_python_interpreter` as a default var.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the virtualenvs pip in a shell:

```
shell: ~/buildbot-env/pip install ${item}
```

Works like a charm. I have no idea what the pip module does with virtualenvs, but it seems pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above, I create a script, say it is called `buildbot.sh`:

```
source ~/buildbot-env/bin/activate
buildbot create-master [and more stuff]
```

Then run it on the remote with a task like this:

```
- name: Create buildbot master
  script: buildbot.sh
```

To me this still seems unneccessary, but it maybe cleaner than running it in a shell command. Your playbook looks cleaner at the cost of not seeing immediately what the script does.

At least some modules do seem to use virtualenv, as both `django_manage` and `rax_clb` already have an inbuilt virtualenv parameter. It may not be such a big step for Ansible to include a command-in-virtenv sort of module.

Comment: Hrm. Yeah, I'm not sure if that's a step forward or backward. A more generic version of it might be the ticket, though. For example, a script which took the venv location from an environment variable, and then passed through the command using $@.