# Not possible to source .bashrc with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I can SSH to the remote host and do a `source /home/username/.bashrc` — everything works fine.
However if I do:

```yaml
- name: source bashrc
  action: command source /home/username/.bashrc
```

I get:

> failed: [hostname] => {"cmd": ["source", "/home/username/.bashrc"], "failed": true, "rc": 2}
> msg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `source` only makes sense when you run it inside an existing shell -- it runs commands *in that shell*, and is thus only useful/helpful when there's an existing shell whose state or configuration you want to change. When you run an ansible action, that **creates a whole new shell**, and runs a command inside *that* shell -- so you wouldn't be updating the environment variables in any other context, so it wouldn't actually have any useful/lasting effecet, even if you got this to run without errors.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If you want to execute a command that expects environment variables to be defined then trying to source something like .bashrc or .bash_profile to defien such variables is a valid use case isn't it?

Comment: @htellez, running `source` only defines variables **for the duration of the shell it runs in**. And that shell has exited (and the variables it defines been lost) by the time that ansible command exits and the next one starts.

Comment: @htellez, ...thus, the only answer here that's actually useful in any meaningful way is [the one by Steve Midgley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27541856/14122), since it has you doing something else in the same shell that ran `source`, before it exited.

Comment: That is exactly the use case I tried to describe, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I tried to describe an scenario in which you want to run something that expects a particular environment defined. I got to this thread because I has getting the same error, and by reading [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27541856/1399310) is that I realized that the ansible's shell task uses sh by default instead of bash. Making the command a bash command explicitly makes `source` work the way you are most likely used to.

Answer (score 112):

You have two options to use source with Ansible. One is with the `shell` module and `/bin/sh` (the default in Ansible).
`source` is called `.` in `/bin/sh`.

So, your command would be:

```yaml
- name: source bashrc
  shell: . /home/username/.bashrc && [the actual command you want run]
```

Note you have to run a command after sourcing `.bashrc` because each SSH session is distinct — every Ansible command runs in a separate SSH transaction.

Your second option is to force Ansible shell to use bash and, then, you can use the `source` command:

```yaml
- name: source bashrc
  shell: source /home/username/.bashrc && [the actual command you want run]
  args:
     executable: /bin/bash
```

Finally, I'll note that you may want to actually source `/etc/profile` if you're on Ubuntu or similar, which more completely simulates a local login.

Comment: Also note this issue has been filed (and commented on by me) as a bug/feature request in Ansible core. But Ansible closed it and said "write a plugin." Bah. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4854

Comment: Are you reading my mind? You answered this 3 moths ago, and I was thinking to edit this `.` -> `source` - and you immediately did this :)

Comment: I tried `source "/etc/profile"` - it didn't work for me. This worked: `source "~/.profile"`

Comment: @warvariuc - /etc/profile is usually found in Ubuntu - and probably some other Debian or Ubuntu derivatives. But other flavors do it differently: sourcing just the ~/.profile will usually only load the user profile context. It won't execute a lot of system-wide stuff that happens for all users when they login. For your particular Unix flavor, search around for the call stack sequence of files that are executed..

Comment: In my case sourcing /etc/profile did not import the user configuration. That was my problem -- I had some env. variables in it. I guess sourcing ~/.profile doesn't automatically source /etc/profile

Comment: @warvariuc - It should work the other way around. There should be some kind of system profile file that runs on login for all users and then variously calls other script files system-wide or for the individual user.. You can see the various files involved in a "normal" login sequence here: http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/Guide_to_linux_boot_sequence - `/etc/profile or /etc/profile.d/*.sh => ~/.bash_profile => ~/.profile => ~/.bashrc`

Comment: > Shell scripts automatically loaded for a login terminal. < My case is to load environment variables for the Ansible's `shell` ([as you already know](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4854)). `shell: . /etc/profile && ember install` did not load user's profile variables. So I had to do `shell: . ~/.profile && ember install`

Comment: @warvariuc - you might consider sourcing them both then. Depending on your setup you might need system stuff set up by /.profile. For example I think it loads everything in /etc/profile.d -- I believe rbenv (for example) installs itself correctly by adding a script to profile.d folder..

Comment: executable: /bin/bash
this is something that is not added to documentation

Comment: What is meant by  [the actual command you want run] ? In my case the ```source``` command is the actual command I want to run.

Comment: @codecowboy - running source alone, afaik, won't do anything. This command is designed to load your bashrc file first, so you have the full environment context, and then run a command. As a simple example, you might have a bash alias defined in bashrc - you could run that command in [the actual command you want to run] area. Or you might run a command which is found in a folder that is added to your path by bashrc.

Comment: another (more ugly) way is to create a wrapper-script, found that idea on another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20572360/1961102

Comment: I have some bash functions defined inside .bashrc and after sourcing the .bashrc. how can I execute/call those functions? I am trying `shell: . ~/.bashrc && nvm install {{ node_version }}` and it is saying, `nvm command not found`. How can I solve this?

Comment: @RaviTezu Are you sure ~ is resolving the way you expect? If you change it to `. /home/[username]/.bashrc` does it work as expected?

Comment: @SteveMidgley I am facing exactly same issue as mentioned by RaviTezu. ~ does resolve to the home directory of the user.

Comment: @RaviTezu: The problem in my case was due to the following lines in .bashrc:

    # If not running interactively, don't do anything
    case $- in
        *i*) ;;
          *) return;;
    esac

This is at least a problem on ubuntu-16.04 xenial64 where .bashrc is not run on non interactive shells which is the case when running commands via ssh. To try it out, set some PATH in ~/.bashrc and run(assuming you have set port 2222 forwarded to 22 on guest os):

ssh -p 2222 ubuntu@127.0.0.1 'echo $PATH'

If the above command doesn't show the PATH you have set in .bashrc then fix .bashrc

Comment: @RaviTezu Were you able to fix the `command not found` error? Facing the same issue when I put the files and sourced the `/etc/profile`

Comment: I wonder that `source /home/username/.bashrc` is working in bash. `source {file}` is used in `csh`, `sh` and `bash` use `. {file}`

Comment: "  shell: source /root/.bashrc "  I get this error: /bin/sh: 1: source: not found, when i execute source manually works...

Answer (score 25):

So `command` will only run executables.  `source` per se is not an executable. (It's a builtin shell command).
Is there any reason why you want to `source` a full environment variable?

There are other ways to include environment variables in Ansible. For example, the `environment` directive:

```
- name: My Great Playbook
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Run my command
      sudo: no
      action: command <your-command>
      environment:
          HOME: /home/myhome
```

Another way is to use the `shell` Ansible module:

```
- name: source bashrc
  sudo: no
  action: shell source /home/username/.bashrc && <your-command>
```

or

```
- name: source bashrc
  sudo: no   
  shell: source /home/username/.bashrc && <your-command>
```

In these cases, the shell instance/environment will terminate once the Ansible step is run.

Comment: almost good, unfortunately /bin/sh doesn't have source commmand only . so `shell source /home/username/.bashrc` becomes `shell . /home/username/.bashrc`

Comment: The shell task takes a parameter as such: `executable=/usr/bin/bash` which will then run it in bash if it is available as such.

Answer (score 21):

I know this answer come too late but I have seen in enough code you can use the sudo option `-i`
so:

```
- name: source bashrc
  shell: sudo -iu {{ansible_user_id}} [the actual command you want run]
```

As said in the documentation

```
The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login shell.  This means that login-specific
               resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.
               If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell.  It also initializes
               the environment to a minimal set of variables, similar to what is present when a user logs in.  The Command environment section below documents in detail how the -i
               option affects the environment in which a command is run.
```

Answer (score 11):

I was experiencing this same issue when trying to get virtualenvwrapper to work on an Ubuntu server. I was using Ansible like this:

```
- name: Make virtual environment
  shell: source /home/username/.bashrc && makevirtualenv virenvname
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

but the source command was not working.

Eventually I discovered that the .bashrc file has a few lines at the top of the file that prevent source from working when called by Ansible:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

I commented out those lines in .bashrc and everything worked as expected after that.

Comment: That is perfectly reasonably and standard header for most `.bashrc` files. You probably want to source a different shell file, or use `BASH_ENV` as discussed in the bash docs.

Answer (score 11):

Many responses recommend to source ~/.bashrc but main problem is that ansible shell is not interactive and ~/.bashrc implementation by default ignores non interactive shell (check its beginning).

The best solution for executing commands as user after its ssh interactive login I found is:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: source user profile file
      #become: yes
      #become_user: my_user  # in case you want to become different user (make sure acl package is installed)
      shell: bash -ilc 'which python' # example command which prints
      register: which_python
    - debug:
      var: which_python
```

bash: '-i' means interactive shell, so .bashrc won't be ignored
      '-l' means login shell which sources full user profile

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me - using `bash -ilc` . It works flawlessly.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried all the options above with **ansible 2.4.1.0** and no one works until another two and here is the detail to re-produce the case.

```
$ cat ~/.bash_aliases 
alias ta="echo 'this is test for ansible interactive shell'";
```

And this is the *ansible test*:

```
- name: Check the basic string operations
  hosts: 127.0.0.1 
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: Test Interactive Bash Failure
    shell: ta
    ignore_errors: True

  - name: Test Interactive Bash Using Source
    shell: source ~/.bash_aliases && ta
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: Test Interactive Bash Using .
    shell: . ~/.bash_aliases && ta
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: Test Interactive Bash Using /bin/bash -ci
    shell: /bin/bash -ic 'ta'
    register: result
    ignore_errors: yes

  - debug: msg="{{ result }}"

  - name: Test Interactive Bash Using sudo -ui
    shell: sudo -ui hearen ta
    register: result
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: Test Interactive Bash Using ssh -tt localhost /bin/bash -ci
    shell: ssh -tt localhost /bin/bash -ci 'ta'
    register: result
    ignore_errors: yes
```

And this is the result:

```
$ ansible-playbook testInteractiveBash.yml 
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: all

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [Check the basic string operations] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [Test Interactive Bash Failure] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ta", "delta": "0:00:00.001341", "end": "2018-10-31 10:11:39.485897", "failed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2018-10-31 10:11:39.484556", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: ta: not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: ta: not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring

TASK [Test Interactive Bash Using Source] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "source ~/.bash_aliases && ta", "delta": "0:00:00.002769", "end": "2018-10-31 10:11:39.588352", "failed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2018-10-31 10:11:39.585583", "stderr": "/bin/bash: ta: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/bash: ta: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring

TASK [Test Interactive Bash Using .] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ". ~/.bash_aliases && ta", "delta": "0:00:00.001425", "end": "2018-10-31 10:11:39.682609", "failed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2018-10-31 10:11:39.681184", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: ta: not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: ta: not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring

TASK [Test Interactive Bash Using /bin/bash -ci] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "/bin/bash -ic 'ta'", 
        "delta": "0:00:00.414534", 
        "end": "2018-10-31 10:11:40.189365", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2018-10-31 10:11:39.774831", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "this is test for ansible interactive shell", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "this is test for ansible interactive shell"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Test Interactive Bash Using sudo -ui] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo

fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sudo -ui hearen ta", "delta": "0:00:00.007906", "end": "2018-10-31 10:11:40.306128", "failed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2018-10-31 10:11:40.298222", "stderr": "sudo: unknown user: i\nsudo: unable to initialize policy plugin", "stderr_lines": ["sudo: unknown user: i", "sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring

TASK [Test Interactive Bash Using ssh -tt localhost /bin/bash -ci] **********************************************************************************************************************
hearen@localhost's password: 
changed: [127.0.0.1]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=8    changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

There are two options worked:

- `shell: /bin/bash -ic 'ta'`
- `shell: ssh -tt localhost /bin/bash -ci 'ta'` but this one requires password input locally.

Answer (score 3):

Well I tried the listed answers but those didn't worked for me while installing ruby through [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). I had to source below lines from `/root/.bash_profile`

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
export PATH
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Finally, I came up with this

```
- shell: sudo su - root -c 'rbenv install -v {{ ruby_version }}'
```

One can use this with any command.

```
- shell: sudo su - root -c 'your command'
```

Comment: This classic approach works with Ansible `2.2.0.0`. However, it nags that I should use `become`, `become_method` and `become_user` instead... I couldn't figure out a combination of those "method" params which would work anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I found become as best solution:

```
- name: Source .bashrc
  shell: . .bashrc
  become: true
```

You can change the user by adding (default: root):

```
- name: Source .bashrc
  shell: . .bashrc
  become: true
  become-user: {your_remote_user}
```

More info here: [Ansible become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html)

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents, i circumnavigated the problem sourcing `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` into `~/.profile` and then using `sudo -iu` as suggested in another answer.

Tried on January 2018 vs Ubuntu 16.04.5

```
- name: Installing Nvm 
  shell: >
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
  args:
    creates: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/.nvm/nvm.sh"
  tags:
    - nodejs    

- name: Source nvm in ~/.profile
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
  lineinfile: >
    dest=~/.profile
    line="source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh"
    create=yes
  tags: 
    - nodejs
  register: output    

- name: Installing node 
  command: sudo -iu {{ ansible_user }} nvm install --lts
  args:
     executable: /bin/bash
  tags:
    - nodejs
```

Answer (score -3):

The right way should be:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: source bashrc file
      shell: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
         - source ~/.bashrc
         - your other command
```

**Note: it's test in `ansible 2.0.2` version**